# Trend in bounties not being manually awarded

Tags: discussion, bounty

I've participated in answering 5 questions with bounties on them.

- The first one, I felt terrible about my answer and aborted the effort.
- The second one, the bounty was offered on a question I had already answered insufficiently.  I subsequently edited my answer and OP selected it promptly.
- Third, fourth, and fifth.  I put significant effort into answering and OP failed to award the bounty manually and my answer was auto selected.

I'm grateful to have been auto selected.  However, I was only awarded half the points.  Anyone following the bounty system knows how this works.  My problem is that if this is the trend, meaning I should expect a large portion of OP's to forget to award bounties, then I'm going to adjust my expectations.  I'm likely going to choose not to participate in answering questions with bounties as the posted bounty amounts are misleading.

It is my opinion that this is partially broken.

#### Suggestions

- Decrease the discount.  50% is steep
- Allow OP some functionality to retrospectively award the remainder of the bounty.

Comment: What could we possibly do to solve this? we can't force the op to choose an answer to add the bounty to because it's relatively common for a bountied question to not receive a satisfactory answer. They've already lost the rep and won't get it back by assigning it, so there's no negative to not awarding it,

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Is this a feature request to change to the bounty system? If yes, in which way?

Comment: @Gothdo this is a discussion as I've tagged it.  I'm a bit frustrated and am starting a discussion to see if I'm off base or if my sentiment resonates.

Comment: I mean, Yeah it's a problem, but it can't really be fixed. It's by design.

Comment: @KevinB is it a problem by design or a problem that can be solved with better design?  I'd argue that better design can solve this problem.

Comment: Let's hear said better design then. How many bounties expire without being awarded that were purposly not awarded vs those that were not awarded due to accidental inactivity?

Comment: @KevinB that is a very good question that I don't have the answer to yet.  I did make a suggestion to allow the remainder to be awarded post grace period.  You can ask the OP if not awarding bounty was intentional.  It doesn't have to be infered by software.  I can think of more.  These might not even be good ideas, but they are ideas.  I started a discussion... so maybe others have ideas.  So far, I've heard 2 people telling me "that's the way it is" and I don't buy that.

Comment: I actually wonder if this is a trend of any kind at all, or if the better question to ask would be what percentage of bounties are only half-awarded.  The main thing I want to avoid is this turning into a discussion about "accept rate" on steroids.

Comment: @Makoto is there a way to answer that question.  I'd like to know.

Comment: SEDE could provide *some* insight, but it'd take a bit to craft that kind of query.

Comment: I don't know the other two but the last one was not a real bounty anyway. The OP was trying to find a freelancer?

Comment: I think it should auto-award 99% of the bounty to the answerer... and the other 1% to me :).

Comment: This issue is really getting under my skin - lately every bounty I've answered has been ignored - i.e. not awarded. Particularly with the effort that is put into some of them, it's a slap in the face - actually there's no slap, there's nothing. I'm actually angry about it, it's happened so many times. I'm sure it's not just happening to me.

Comment: @YvetteColomb correct. Not just you. I don't answer bounties anymore.

Comment: @piRSquared I still get rep from them, it's the rudeness I don't like

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunatelly sometimes the person who started the bounty doesn't award it even if the question receives a good answer, but I doubt there's much we can do about that. We shouldn't force users to award bounties, because often bountied questions don't receive a satisfactory answer (as [Kevin B wrote in comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334479/trend-in-bounties-not-being-manually-awarded#comment394819_334479)).

As for allowing the OP to retrospectively award the remainder of the bounty—there already is a 24‑hour grace period for awarding the bounty, and I don't think that extending it is a good idea. If the OP doesn't award the bounty during that 24 hours, it's unlikely that they'd award the bounty later.